# Cycle2 slider-css attribute

Tags: jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I'm trying to applying custom CSS to each slide in my Cycle2 carousel.

The attribute, to add to the carousel's conatining div, is:

```
data-cycle-slide-css
```

The doc's says that the value should be an 'object hash'.

I'm not sure what this means.

I've tried giving it the value:

```
"{margin:-30px;}"
```

But that's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try  `.cycle-slideshow{margin:-30px;}`  in your .css file

Comment: Learn Here : [divs as slide elements](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
data-cycle-slide-css='{"margin":"-30px"}'
```

You can see an example of this syntax in the Offset Stack section of the Shuffle demo here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/shuffle.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Corey! Thank you for your answer. You may want to consider editing in the relevant part of the Shuffle Demo into your answer, as links tend to break after a while, and we want your answer to remain useful for future users of Stack Overflow.